# Why does Collectors.toUnmodifiableList use a type check of the intermediate accumulator?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I see the following code (JDK 16, JDK 17):

```java
    public static <T>
    Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toUnmodifiableList() {
        return new CollectorImpl<>(ArrayList::new, List::add,
                                   (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                                   list -> {
                                       if (list.getClass() == ArrayList.class) { // ensure it's trusted
                                           return SharedSecrets.getJavaUtilCollectionAccess()
                                                               .listFromTrustedArray(list.toArray());
                                       } else {
                                           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                                       }
                                   },
                                   CH_NOID);
    }
```

- [JDK 16](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-16+36/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#L297)
- [JDK 17](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+35/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#L297)

What's the point of using `if (list.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {` check? Why not simply make this code as simple as

```java
return new CollectorImpl<>(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add,                                          
                           (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },              
                           list -> SharedSecrets.getJavaUtilCollectionAccess().listFromTrustedArray(list.toArray()),                                                                  
                           CH_NOID);
```

By replacing `List::add` with `ArrayList::add` we're providing the most specific method handle of the class, not an interface.
The last code uses an assumption that the accumulator instance will be passed to the 'accumulator', the 'combiner' and the 'finisher' parameters as an ArrayList instance (actually, it will, since CollectorImpl uses the same invariant generic variable A for all parameters). I don't see any difference between an IllegalArgumentException and a ClassCastException except the code complexity and an additional check in the finisher.

Comment: [The check isn't there](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#L297) in OpenJDK 11, and for some reason I can't find `toUnmodifiableList` in OpenJDK 10.

Comment: Thanks.
I'll fix the description.
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-16+36/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#L297
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17+35/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java

Comment: The [commit introduce the change](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/d7128e7daceca8b3717f3a3cd2f7a6ddba6f215d#diff-b6fbc74ba8b77c1725ea8d7aa1618c5111468028ee097044351fec60e2a219e8) and the [related issue JDK-8254090](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254090)

Comment: See also [this comment](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/449#issuecomment-704001706)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The change from

```
Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toUnmodifiableList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               list -> (List<T>)List.of(list.toArray()),
                               CH_NOID);
}
```

to

```
public static <T>
Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toUnmodifiableList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>(ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               list -> {
                                   if (list.getClass() == ArrayList.class) { // ensure it's trusted
                                       return SharedSecrets.getJavaUtilCollectionAccess()
                                                           .listFromTrustedArray(list.toArray());
                                   } else {
                                       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                                   }
                               },
                               CH_NOID);
}
```

happened in two steps. The step in between was

```
Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toUnmodifiableList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               list -> (List<T>)SharedSecrets.getJavaUtilCollectionAccess()
                                                             .listFromTrustedArray(list.toArray()),
                               CH_NOID);
}
```

This first step was introduced for performance reasons (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8156071) and later some noticed that this leads to a security problem (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254090, https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/449#issuecomment-704001706) and therefore the second change was done.